# Are backpack and tool upgrades separate or shared among players?

Tags: stardew-valley

We are about to have the money to buy the backpack upgrade, but does every player have to buy it or is upgrades progress common between all players?

Same thing goes with the tools upgrades. Are they separate for every player, or if one player does the upgrade it's upgraded for everybody?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Tool and backpack upgrades are separate for each player. It does get expensive fast to have to spend a few thousand gold and metal bars several times, but it is worth noting that you can share your tools with you friends by placing them in a chest, since anyone can access any chest.

As a side note, while Clint is upgrading a tool, he will still be open for business (shopping, upgrading, cracking geodes) for players who are not having their tool upgraded.

Source: I've already spent over a whole season in multiplayer with friends.